# The magnetic dipole moment of electrons is not conserved?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electrons

The electron has a constant value of its magnetic dipole [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?muem%7Csearch_for=electron+magnetic). How then is "[Magnetic dipole moments are neither conserved nor quantized](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/738417/46708)" to be understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons have a characteristic magnetic dipole moment. It's one of their properties. However, processes that create or destroy electrons don't conserve it. For example, in K capture (e+p->n+ν), the electron magnetic moment pretty much disappears. The magnetic moments of the other particles are tiny.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Did the neutrino a magnetic dipole moment at all? See the question [Empirical evidence or theoretical predictions for magnetic dipole moments of neutrinos?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738448/empirical-evidence-or-theoretical-predictions-for-magnetic-dipole-moments-of-neu)?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler it does not have one intrinsically, and even when calculated as contributions from higher diagrams is much to small to account for the difference.