# Empirical evidence or theoretical predictions for magnetic dipole moments of neutrinos?

Tags: neutrinos, magnetic-moment

Neither NIST nor Wikipedia say anything about a magnetic dipole moment in neutrinos. Since neutrinos typically pass through normal matter unimpeded and undetected, empirical evidence of a magnetic dipole moment seems unlikely.

Has science attempted a theoretical prediction based on - for example - possible conservation of magnetic moments?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06883

Comment: if you feel up to the math https://indico.fnal.gov/event/44782/contributions/196361/attachments/134477/166463/nuDMSnowmass.pdf

Comment: @annav No, Anna, unfortunately I do not feel up to mathematics. My knowledge ends with integration, differentiation, vector and matrix calculation.

Comment: You should be able to click on the PDF link to see the paper; arXiv has free access. There *are* theoretical predictions, based on various assumptions. They rely on the fact that in the Standard Model a chargeless neutrino can become a charged W and an oppositely charged lepton; this is one of the basic interaction vertices of weak nuclear interactions.

Comment: @Ghoster I saw it at that moment. Sorry. In a first rush I wanted to delete the question. But why? I think a short answer from your side would be helpful. Or does wiki and NIST have such data?

Comment: No neutrino magnetic moment has been detected; this would be a Nobel-level discovery. As far as I know, experiments simple place upper limits on it.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12817 might have the upper limit data.

Comment: I don’t want to write an answer since I’m not an expert on this, but it seems like a reasonable question so someone may answer. I am however confident that “conservation of magnetic moments” is not a thing. There is no theoretical reason to expect them to be conserved, and plenty of evidence that they are not.

Comment: See Figure 6 (top right) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.11330 for the most current limits.